# Table cell moving after onclick

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a page whos players update their stats 
for each stat I have a cell, with description and (+) whos give them the option for chose which one to update, but when you trying to click  the whole table is going left
its no script whos do it or something like that

[this is how its need to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAWbF.png)

[this is the result after click\hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEf7f.png)

I moved position: absolut
but still, nothing happened

```
position: static;;
}
.titlestat {
    right:20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-3px;
    margin-right:40px;
    right:20px;
}
.substat {
    right:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-right:40px;
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
}
.upstat {
    right:20px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:24px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding:3px 10px;
    padding-top:2px;
    border:solid 1px #693b23;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px #000,0px 4px 3px 
rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
color:#fff;
margin-top:0px;
margin-right:153px;
text-decoration:none;
border-radius:6px;
transition:0.3s;
-webkit-transition:0.3s;
-moz-transition:0.3s;
right:20px;
}
.upstat:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px #000,0px 4px 4px 
rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
text-shadow:0px 0px 16px #fff,0px 0px 16px #fff;
}
.statsupdiv {
background:url(../img/code/chatbg.jpg);
width:472px;
margin-right:10px;
padding:10px 0px;
border-right:solid 1px #693b23;
border-left:solid 1px #693b23;
border-bottom:solid 1px #693b23;
box-shadow:1px 0px 0px #000,-1px 0px 0px #000,0px 1px 0px #000;
margin-bottom:8px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
}
.stats1 {margin-right:-240px;margin-top:0px;}
.stats2 {margin-right:2px;margin-top:0px;}
.stats3 {margin-right:-240px;margin-top:80px;}
.stats4 {margin-right:2px;margin-top:80px;}
```

Comment: share your html..

Comment: we need your HTML in order to help, you can upload it to https://codesandbox.io/